# Adobe PDF to PPT API

Tags: pdf, powerpoint, adobe

Does Adobe provide an official API to convert PDF file to PPT?

https://www.adobe.com/in/acrobat/online/pdf-to-ppt.html

Note: I am *only* looking for official APIs.

Comment: Check out Adobe PDF Services API - Look at the Convert service https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-services.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the Node.js SDK for [Adobe PDF Services API](http://adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-services.html) your code might look like this...

```
// Create an ExecutionContext using 
// credentials and create a new 
// operation instance.
const executionContext = PDFServicesSdk.ExecutionContext.create(credentials),
exportPDF = PDFServicesSdk.ExportPDF,
exportPdfOperation = exportPDF.Operation.createNew(exportPDF.SupportedTargetFormats.PPTX);

// Set operation input from a source file
const input = PDFServicesSdk.FileRef.createFromLocalFile('resources/exportPDFInput.pdf');
exportPdfOperation.setInput(input);

// Execute the operation and Save the result to the specified location.
exportPdfOperation.execute(executionContext)
.then(result => result.saveAsFile('output/exportPdfOutput.pptx'))
```